Is there any good way to guess how much load my floors would take
... Short of hiring an engineer, of course.
I have visions of a formal library in what the builders thought was going to be the second-floor master bedroom. I am certain I can get away with overloaded bookcases along all the walls. I am less certain about how much additional storage I can get away with by having bookcases at right angles to those, extending into the room.
The plan, such as it is, would be to have them at right angles to the floor joists, so at least the load is distributed across multiple choice. However, that also means that if I have several on one side of the room each joist might be carrying the weight of more than one.
Are there any rule of thumb SWAGs I could use to get an initial guess? If it's completely unreasonable, then it's worth not worth paying for an engineer.
Or should I just run the sagulator on it?

If you can figure the weight of the bookcases plus books and it comes below 40 pounds per square foot(common for floors built to code), you might be okay(maybe).  Formal library makes me think of heavy oak made floor to ceiling book shelves.

Oak built-ins is one possibility. Other woods are also possible, including face frames in one wood while the carcass is built from something lighter and cheaper. Batrister's modules are another possibility, and would be period appropriate for the house. Styling the shelves to mimic campaign furniture would also be a possibility, but moves more to the steampunk then historical range, which is not necessarily a drawback. Floor to ceiling, or nearly so, is certainly part of what I'm imagining.

The weight isn't (mostly) the book shelves. It is the books on them - the shelves are heavy compared to regular shelves but small in volume - and therefore weight - compared to the books placed on them.
Those books definitely add up. A quick look finds a 75 lb/cubic foot paper weight.  Using that as a ballpark, if you have shelves filled end to end but 6" deep books (to keep the math simple) and 8" tall  books(to keep the math simple) and 6 shelves (to keep the math simple) then you have 2/3 (8") x 6 (shelves) x 1/2 (6") x 75 lbs./cubic foot = 150 lbs. per linear foot of book shelves.
A quick search shows 40 lbs./square foot as the basic minimum strength for residential buildings. Using that as a minimum would recommend 150/40 = 3.75 square feet for one linear foot of book shelves. If that foot of book shelves is 9" deep (to keep the math simple, with the books 6") then that would mean allowing 3 square feet in front of each book shelf. Which is actually quite reasonable, until you do things like book shelves on both sides (now need 6 feet in between, not 3 feet like you might have in a real library) and it gets worse with perpendicular parts added, etc.
On the other hand, if the room is something like 10' x 15' and put book shelves mostly around the walls (but not the full amount - doors, windows (maybe 3 shelves instead of 6), etc.) and you have a nice reading table in the middle then I think you could get a really nice library without exceeding any typical limits.

"Books weigjh like trees.". Or, as a friend of a friend put it, after having  helped relocate a large personal library, "From now on I only help illiterates move!"

I'm going to face an entirely different challenge in terms of finding wall space for both books and art. That may call for bookcases with doors.

Keeping the center open for a desk and reading chairs is the standing plan; I just want to understand how far I can push things as the library continues unbounded growth. What can I say, I like displaying my hunting trophies.
